# Making backspace button in java that deletes the last character in a Textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator, backspace

I want to make a button that acts like a backspace but I cant find the perfect code for doing it, like I made a button that adds certain characters to a Textview using append() method in a single line of code instead of making a multiple line thingy.
 So my question is: is there a way to do it in a backspace button code, I know I can make a multiple line/long code, but is there an opposite to append()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for character backspace:

```
buttonBackspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
           String word = editText.getText().toString();               
           int input = word.length();
              if (input > 0){
                 editText.setText(word.substring(0, input-1));
              }          
           }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried the code and it works even better than I imagined

Answer (score 0):

To remove Character using Backspace Button.

First initialize view

```
   Button BackSpaceButton;
```

Then Find the View

```
   BackSpaceButton = findViewById(R.id.BackBtn);
```

Then Add Listener to Button

```
   BackSpaceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
             String word = EditTextInputNumbers.getText().toString();
             int input = word.length();
             if (input > 0) {
              EditTextInputNumbers.setText(word.substring(0, input - 1));
          }
        }
       });
```

Comment: Please avoid any duplication. This answer is similar to the accepted answer. If you would like to add any point please leave it as a comment for the accepted answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.